# Facial Recognition State of the Art Measurement

Tags: facial-recognition

I would expect issues with the Facial Recognition technology to prompt evaluators to measure performance with metrics such as:

- accuracy (e.g. false positives)
- [poor image quality input handling](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/dc45/2f3e531c4057c930f0538d5652ad9034d1aa.pdf)
- speed of algorithm

What are the metrics used to gauge state of the art Facial Recognition?  Please feel free to add the list

Comment: Take a look at any recent paper of the topic, and see how they evaluate their results.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question.  What does "issues determine drive metric genesis" mean?

Comment: @D.W.  Thanks for the feedback.  I updated the post: does it clarify?